# Angular CLI and react JavaScript run in same project how to make it possible

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, microservices, angular-cli-v9

This is my package.json file if I want to run both Angular CLI 10 and reactjs in same platform how can I make it possible. It should be possible because both background is same if we menu-plate router we can run both in same platform. Do any have any plane for it? It yes please explain it with code.

```js
{
  "name": "school-Test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4500",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "build:browser:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:browser:prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.11",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngmodule/material-carousel": "^0.6.0",
    "@ngx-share/button": "^7.1.4",
    "@ngx-share/buttons": "^7.1.4",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@ngx-utils/cookies": "^4.0.1",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^9.0.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-l10n": "^9.3.0",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^9.2.0",
    "angular2-focus": "^1.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^7.1.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.2",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-drag-scroll": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-img-zoom": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-stripe": "^9.1.2",
    "nouislider": "^14.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.53",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: why there is no seance if we want to use multiple tech from one platform then ? If both background are same then there a way to connect both. if we can connect both tech in one platform we can mould our project with latest adaption of both language.  This is not homework this is r&d question .

Comment: I don't think running both in the same project makes sense in any way. If you're looking for connecting projects (so they use same interfaces etc) look at [nx](https://nx.dev/), it's for monorepos, supports Angular and React.